# Need kubectl jsonpath parameter to get array entry indexed by string

Tags: kubectl

I have some scripts that pipe "kubectl ... -o json" to "jq".  I've been converting many of those occurrences to use the "jsonpath" parameter to kubectl so I can skip the jq step.

There's one set of these that I've been unable to convert, because of punctuation issues.  The original line looks something like this:

```
kubectl ... -o json | jq -r '.data["application.properties"]'
```

In the json, there is a "data" map whose keys can have periods in the names, so I have to index it as an array, with the name as the key.  This works fine using jq.

The simple-minded conversion of this to jsonpath looks something like this:

```
kubectl ... -o=jsonpath="{.data["application.properties"]}"
```

This fails with:

```
error: error parsing jsonpath {.data[application.properties]}, invalid array index application.properties
```

This doesn't appear to be a quoting problem, as it is clearly detecting what my attempted array index is, it just won't let me use it.

Is there any way to do this entirely with jsonpath?

Comment: Actually, I just realized I could think of this in a different way, looking for ".data.application\.properties", and that works fine in jsonpath. I'll self-answer this after a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to convert

```
{.data["application.properties"]}
```

To:

```
{.data.application\.properties}
```

(with quoting as required)

Answer (score 0):

Using jq

`kubectl get secret some-secret -o json | jq '.data["application.properties"]' | tr -d "\"\n"`

and without as David suggested above

`kubectl get secret some-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.application\.properties}'`

Comment: Thanks, but read the first line of my post.

Comment: Yea for windows git bash that doesn't seem to work, throws some exception.

Comment: Ok, interesting. Not a problem for me, but I'll note that.